# Is $E[\sum_{i=1}^\infty a^i \varepsilon_i]=0$ for $\{\varepsilon_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ White noise?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\{\varepsilon_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ be White noise, i.e. a sequence of stochastic variables such that $E[\varepsilon_i]=0$, $\text{Var}(\varepsilon_i)=\sigma^2<\infty$ and $\text{Cov}(\varepsilon_i,\varepsilon_j)=0$ if $i\neq j$, lastly let $|a|<1$. Is it then true that  $E[\sum_{i=1}^\infty a^i \varepsilon_i]=0$.

I know monotone convergence, but terms are not necessarily positive and dominated convergence, but it isn't immediate clear to me what could dominate the above.
Any insight would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes if the expectation is 0. Note the expected value of modulus is defined. The sequence is dominated by $\sum a^i |\epsilon_i|$. The expectation of which is finite, because you can exchange sum and expectation as every term is positive.

Comment: Doh. Of course. Thanks :)

Comment: Np, very rarely, do you actually see a probability question when the OP actually made a good attempt. I encourage you to use math se more often. Well phrased questions with research effort is always welcome.